# Where does the application cookie go when created?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authentication, cookies, owin

I'm playing around with the authentication using Owin according to a [blog](http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2015/Apr/29/Adding-minimal-OWIN-Identity-Authentication-to-an-Existing-ASPNET-MVC-Application) and when I execute the following, I'm supposed to get an (application) cookie. I'm unsure how to verify that I actually got one. So it very well might be there, somewhere in the memory or on the disk but I'm too ignorant of security issues to determine that.

```
List<Claim> claims = new List<Claim> { new Claim("Donkey", "Hazaa") };
ClaimsIdentity identity = new ClaimsIdentity(
  claims, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties
{
  AllowRefresh = false,
  IsPersistent = false,
  ExpiresUtc = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(1)
});
```

I can't verify by being able/unable to log in, since this is just a dummy without any backbone yet. The only thing I need to do at this stage is to confirm that **something** gets **somewhere** and that it **vanishes** when a minute has passed. It'd be awesomely awesome if there was an actual cookie file popping up somewhere and then poofing away after a while. Is there such?

Answer (score 0):

Of course it is, but the Cookie is sent to the browser once the authentication was requested and validated. The cookie has the same behavior as in previous version of cookie auth with forms authentication, so is a task for the browser to receive and manage the cookie; on each HTTP request, the browser sends its cookies, which are processed by OWIN to check authentication.

Take the code and implement a simple authorization on memory (like user: abc, pass: 123) and check how the browser receives the cookie. By the way, the only difference between cookie and token validation is that the cookie is automatically sent on every request, whilst on token auth you need to explicitly send the token information on header.

Be aware that cookie authentication is intended for browsers, as mobile applications or other applications that need to connect to your API will not have access to the cookie response, like in a desktop app.

Regards

Comment: I followed [a hint](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/904767) and got to the *cookies.sqlite* file but when I open it, there's hardly anything readable. How **exactly** do I go about verifying that the cookie's been delivered to me?

Comment: Execute the login on a browser. Then, you can see the generated cookie using firebug (Firefox) or the chrome developer tool. Btw the content of the cookie will be encrypted if you send only claims, for security purposes